# xcodebuild -create-xcframework - BCSymbolMaps missing - on M1 Xcode 14.0

Tags: ios, xcode, xcodebuild, xcframework

I use the same bash script for building the XCFramework for at least 2 years and everything worked successfully until the moment I switched my Mac to M1 and my Xcode is 14.0.

The script is pretty standard (see below).

On MacPro M1, Xcode 14.0 I get the following error (the same script works just fine on Xcode 13.1).

```
error: the path does not point to a valid debug symbols file: /Users/*******/build/Release-iphoneos.xcarchive/BCSymbolMaps/*
```

Indeed when I look at build/Release-iphoneos.xcarchive folder - the BCSymbolMaps is not there. I verified that the Xcode setting "debug information format" is dwarf with dsym file.

Can someone please help me understand what is this error? and why it started happening on M1, Xcode 14.0 ?

Thank you

See my bash build script below.

```
# Build the framework for device and for simulator (using
# all needed architectures).
xcodebuild archive -scheme "${TARGET_NAME}" -destination="iOS" -sdk iphonesimulator SKIP_INSTALL=NO BUILD_LIBRARIES_FOR_DISTRIBUTION=YES -archivePath "${SRCROOT}/build/Release-iphonesimulator"
xcodebuild archive -scheme "${TARGET_NAME}" -destination="iOS" -sdk iphoneos        SKIP_INSTALL=NO BUILD_LIBRARIES_FOR_DISTRIBUTION=YES -archivePath "${SRCROOT}/build/Release-iphoneos"



ls -l "${SRCROOT}/build/"

# https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/655768

# First, get all the UUID filepaths for BCSymbolMaps, because these are randomly generated and need to be individually added as the `-debug-symbols` parameter. The dSYM path is always the same so that one is manually added
echo "XCFramework: Generating IPHONE BCSymbolMap paths..."
IPHONE_BCSYMBOLMAP_PATHS=(${SRCROOT}/build/Release-iphoneos.xcarchive/BCSymbolMaps/*)
IPHONE_BCSYMBOLMAP_COMMANDS=""
for path in "${IPHONE_BCSYMBOLMAP_PATHS[@]}"; do
  IPHONE_BCSYMBOLMAP_COMMANDS="$IPHONE_BCSYMBOLMAP_COMMANDS -debug-symbols $path "
  echo $IPHONE_BCSYMBOLMAP_COMMANDS
done

echo "XCFramework: Generating IPHONE BCSymbolMap paths... --> Done"

# XCFramework with debug symbols - see https://pspdfkit.com/blog/2021/advances-in-xcframeworks/#built-in-support-for-bcsymbolmaps-and-dsyms
xcodebuild -create-xcframework -allow-internal-distribution \
    -framework "${SRCROOT}/build/Release-iphoneos.xcarchive/Products/Library/Frameworks/${FRAMEWORK_NAME}.framework" \
    -debug-symbols "${SRCROOT}/build/Release-iphoneos.xcarchive/dSYMs/${FRAMEWORK_NAME}.framework.dSYM" \
    $IPHONE_BCSYMBOLMAP_COMMANDS \
    -framework "${SRCROOT}/build/Release-iphonesimulator.xcarchive/Products/Library/Frameworks/${FRAMEWORK_NAME}.framework" \
    -debug-symbols "${SRCROOT}/build/Release-iphonesimulator.xcarchive/dSYMs/${FRAMEWORK_NAME}.framework.dSYM" \
    -output "${SF_RELEASE_DIR}/${FRAMEWORK_NAME}.xcframework"
```

Comment: Just might be helpful to know that M chips work on an ARM based architecture so that XCFramework or any other part mentioned above may not work as expected. I had same behaviour and I had to switched from VS to VS Preview for instance.

Answer (score 2):

bit code is not supported by xcode14 so bcsymbolmaps are no more relevant for xcode14